# In VuePress using a component at the start of a new line in Markdown does not wrap the line in a <p> tag

Tags: vue.js, markdown, vuepress

Whether it's a built-in component like Badge or a custom component, if you start a new line with that component reference, the VuePress markdown parser does not treat it like a new paragraph.

```
This is text
 
<Badge text="TBD" /> foo
```

Gets rendered as...

```
<p>This is text</p>
<span class="badge">TBD</span> foo
```

But if you use it like this

```
This is text
 
foo <Badge text="TBD" /> bar
```

...it renders as...

```
<p>This is text</p>
<p>foo <span class="badge">TBD</span> bar</p>
```

Is there any way to force components to be rendered like any other text and be injected into a **p tag** if they are inline and at the start of a new line?